# Putting a timestamp to the records after pulling at regular intervals

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I have one database table with the following columns .

```
ZoneName ZoneCount
```

I want to copy this data to another db table with a time stamp .

I can copy using the following query

```
insert into ... select * FROM ...
```

My question is how do i add **timestamp** to it , if i am running this query at every 15 min.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOW()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

```
insert into destination_table (col1, col2, col3)
select ZoneName, ZoneCount, NOW() 
FROM source_table
```

Comment: yes ..actually this works ...i was thinking that in select statement we can only use the columns that are there in the table ...thanks